# Using DbGeography with Entity Framework 6 in Class library(Package) and ASP .NET 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I am trying to use DbGeography class in the model. I have added Entity Framework 6 to Class Library(Package) and added a reference to the library to ASP .NET 5 project. Have been used "System.Data.Entity.Spatial" namespace and no errors displayed. But when I build solution there are 2 errors thrown:

1. "Error  CS0234  The type or namespace name 'Entity' does not exist in
   the namespace 'System.Data' (are you missing an assembly
   reference?)"
2. Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'DbGeography' could not be
   found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

There is code of my model:

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
using System.Data.Entity.Spatial;

namespace ExampleNamespace
{
    public class ExampleDbGeography
    {
        //some other fields

        public DbGeography StartPoint { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My class library project.json file:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "description": "Example Class Library",
  "authors": [ "ZV" ],
  "tags": [ "" ],
  "projectUrl": "",
  "licenseUrl": "",
  "frameworks": {
    "net451": {
      "dependencies": {
        "EntityFramework": "6.1.3"
      }
    },
    "dotnet5.4": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.CSharp": "4.0.1-beta-23516",
        "System.Collections": "4.0.11-beta-23516",
        "System.Linq": "4.0.1-beta-23516",
        "System.Runtime": "4.0.21-beta-23516",
        "System.Threading": "4.0.11-beta-23516"
      }
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework": "3.0.0-rc1-final"
  }
}
```